# Downloading Javascript object as a .json file, but JSON is not formatted

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a function that is taking a javascript object and attempting to download it into a .json file, but it's being printed as flat text. Is there any way I can get this to be .json formatted in the file? Also would prefer not to have to install any third-party libraries if possible.

```
downloadJSON(jsonFile: any, fileName: string){
        let sJson = JSON.stringify(jsonFile);
        let file = new Blob([sJson], {type: 'application/json'})
        let element = document.createElement('a');
        let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        element.setAttribute('href', url);
        element.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click(); // simulate click
        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
```

Comment: I think you'll have to install a JSON prettifier library for formatting. JSON by default is going to be minimized.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)`, or however many spaces you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

It never fails that once I post on here, I immediately find the answer elsewhere after having search for hours. It's in this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pretty-print-json-string-in-javascript/

Use JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, space) method to convert JavaScript objects into strings in a pretty format.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get .json formatted file, you must set the file name with the suffix '.json'.